# Keystore -Detect if the lock screen is changed or wiped

Tags: android, keystore, lockscreen

I have read [Analysis of Secure Key Storage Solutions on Android](http://www.cs.kun.nl/~erikpoll/publications/AndroidSecureStorage.pdf)
and I want to use setEncryptionRequired() so that my keys must be encrypted at rest (pre-M Android).
Changing the pin/pattern on the lock screen as described [here](https://doridori.github.io/android-security-the-forgetful-keystore/#sthash.HcDKSOAg.dpbs) on Android < 6.0 will delete the keystore, and leave my encrypted data useless.
How can I automatically detect if the lock screen is changed or wiped?